# How do I call a php script from Grails?

Tags: php, grails, groovy

OK, I am creating a grails project, but I have php legacy code.  Rather than re-invent the wheel, is there a way to call the php code from my groovy?

For example, there is a php script called post_handler.php that has a postRequest method that has $data (the data required to do the post) as the input param.  How would I go about just calling post_handler->postRequest(data)?  I'm sorry if this question has already been asked and answered.  I looked and couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably put a thin API on top of your PHP code that would allow you make REST calls that return JSON.  You can then very easily use your existing PHP as a data layer if you so choose.  You can use [HttpBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/home.html) to very easily make calls to an external REST service and then it will demarshall the JSON string to an object.

If a web service is too slow for your communication layer, you may want to look at [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/).  Facebook uses this to communicate between PHP and Java.  There are some tutorials [here](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/Tutorial) if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the [PHP plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/php) but it's quite old at this point. It uses [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/) so you could probably look at [the plugin source](http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-php/trunk/) and see how it was integrated, and do something similar with a newer version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the PHP file is you can use the groovy String.execute()
http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute().  Which basically allows you to execute anything as if you were on a command line.  I know nothing about PHP but I would imagine that you can execute PHP scripts from the command line.